Java BigDecimal Precision Issue: Result Auto Rounding During Calculation
I'm working on a Java program to calculate a financial result using BigDecimal to ensure precision. Despite setting a high precision and using RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN in my calculations, the result is still being auto-rounded off when I multiply two BigDecimal values.
Here’s my code:
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

private static BigDecimal next(BigDecimal value, BigDecimal rate) {
    System.out.println(value + "---" + rate);

    BigDecimal hundred = new BigDecimal("100");

    // Divide rate by 100 with high precision
    BigDecimal rateDivided = rate.divide(hundred, 20, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

    // Add 1 to the divided rate
    BigDecimal increment = BigDecimal.ONE.add(rateDivided);

    // Multiply the original value by the increment
    BigDecimal result = value.multiply(increment);

    // Round the final result to 4 decimal places
    result = result.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

    System.out.println("Final result: " + result);
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("9584.0000");
    BigDecimal rate = new BigDecimal("8.0000");

    BigDecimal result = next(value, rate);
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
}

Input:
value = 9584.0000
rate = 8.0000
Expected Output:
10350.7197
Actual Output:
10350.7200
I’ve tried using higher precision for intermediate steps and RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN but the final result is still being rounded to 10350.7200. I need the precision to match exactly to four decimal places without rounding off the last digits prematurely.
Using MathContext for higher precision.
Increasing the scale during division and multiplication.
Rounding only at the final step.
Despite these efforts, the result is still being rounded. Could anyone help me identify what I might be missing or suggest another approach?

why is 10350.7197 expected and not 10350.7200 ? isn't 9584 * 1.08 = 10350.72 (or 10350.7200) ? { 9584 * 1.08 = 9538 * 1 + 9584 * 0.08 = 9584 + 766.72 or any calculator }

@user85421 I am trying to convert a fortran program into java, and while fortran does the same calculation it results in a different precision value like 10350.7197 so I was wondering why java isn't behaving the same and how can I make it more precise like fortran is.

The Fortran program is  the one that's imprecise.  Get out  a  pad and do the math. The Java is getting the exact answer. A guess is that the Fortran is using IEEE single precision floats, which have only about 6-7 digits of precision.

Using Java floats float z = 9584.0f * 1.08f; gives z = 10350.721.

no idea about Fortran, but by single basic school math, (again) 9584 * 1.08 = 10350.72 and NOT 10350.7197 -- seems like Fortran is using IEEE float since 10350.72F is actually 10350.7197265625 (print new BigDecimal(10350.72F) in Java), but, as you wrote, "to ensure precision" the result should be 10350.72

If you're doing financial math, don't use decimals except during intermediary operations. E.g. you have an integer that represents an amount in 1/10th of a cent (so $124,56 is 124560), then you do your math on that, rounding the result to an integer using banker's rounding (i.e. rounding to the nearest even integer). Then when you need to present that number you can turn it into a decimal and round it to 2 decimal places but that's about it. No need for big decimals. That said: the amounts you're working with don't need BigDecimal to begin with, double is plenty big.
